# Database structure not loading in MVC Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sql-database

I am having trouble opening my database model structure in the SQL Server Object Explorer. 
It usually works, but just today it suddenly wouldn't open.

[image]

It just freezes on this loading screen and after waiting almost an hour, I get the message that import database structure has failed.

I can, however, view the data within the database but can't seem to look at the structure.

I am using SQL Server 2014 with Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Turns out it was Microsoft's server issue. They were experiencing technical difficulties.